# Append query inserting string WITH special characters from user input

Tags: vba, character

I have a database that I am building where users can add new records at will.  The record has a client name which often contains " ' , . special characters.  Whenever these appear, the append query bombs out.  I know I can filter out these special characters to avoid this, but I don't want to do that if I can help it.

```
DoCmd.RunSQL ("INSERT INTO tblPlanSpecs ( PlanName ) SELECT '" & (NewPlan) & "'")
```

I want the user to click the "add new client" button, type in the client and plan names into the text boxes, and then click "add" and this new client/plan name will be added as a new record to the database, and the two text boxes will be populated with the correct client name and plan name.  They need to contain the ' " , . etc because that really is the client's name.  Is this possible?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use escape characters like the following...

```
DoCmd.RunSQL "Insert Into tblPlanSpecs (PlanName) Values(" & Chr(34) & Replace([NewPlan], """", """""") & Chr(34) & ");"
```